# What is the correct way to dismiss flutter dialog and current page?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

My page have some api request, when api return error, I will show the dialog.

When I click the confirm button, the dialog should be dismiss and current page will finish.

```
var count = 0;
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
  return count++ == 2;
});
```

but sometimes it works sometimes it not work.(When I reopen this page)

I also tried

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

```
Navigator.pop(context);//pop dialog
Navigator.pop(context);//pop current page
```

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

All of the above is sometimes works sometimes not work.

Why it is so unstable? And what is the correct way to handle dialog and page navigate?

Answer (score 2):

```
final res = await showDialog(context: context, builder: {
  // pop dialog
  Navigator.pop(context, true);
});
if (res) {
  // pop current page
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

The page pop action should depends on the dialog pop action

Answer (score 0):

```
    what about this The Navigator.popUntil 
    
    this method is called with a predicate that matches the current page (specified by its route name), which removes all pages from the navigation stack except for the current page. Finally, the Navigator.pop method is called to remove the current page from the stack and return control to the previous page.

 // Dismiss the dialog and current page
  Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
 // Replace '/' with the route name of your current page
  Navigator.pop(context);
```

this works based on the case you mentioned, however, you also need to check the behavior of your page which might have a difference stack flow.

Comment: what is `withName` I have to fill?

Comment: let's say I have a subscription page, because we want to use the modalRoute I need to register it at routes in materialApp, example: '/subscription': (context) =>SubscriptionPage(), shortly I do post requests to update the subscription however because it failed request we show the dialog and in confirm button so i do this :
  Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/subscription'));
  Navigator.pop(context);

Comment: But If I don't use modalRoute  to register any page?